# Richfaces Compatibility Problems with Internet Explorer 11

Tags: jsf, cross-browser, richfaces, internet-explorer-11, incompatibility

I am developing a web application using RichFaces / JSF. The application behaved as expected on Safari, Mozilla, Chrome, and IE 9, however, I encountered serious compatibility problems with IE 11.

- When a rich:modalPanel opens up, the dialog and buttons are completely greyed out.
- The h:inputTextArea displays all of the server side code generated as opposed to being empty.
- When I click the rich:calendar icon, it does not popup a calendar, even though I have set popup 
  to true in the attributes.

I do not encounter any of the above problems in any other browser except for IE 11

When I debugged my web application in IE 11 Developer Tools, some messages related to the above mentioned problems were:

- The function is undefined or null: selectNodes  (JavaScript)
- RichFaces skin issues

I am running JBoss version 4.2.1.GA and RichFaces version 3.3.2

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

RichFaces 3 is only supported in Internet Explorer ≤ 8.  Try using the the Meta Tag *http-equiv* to set the document mode to IE 8.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff966528(v=vs.85).aspx

Or better yet, upgrade to RichFaces 4 (4.3.4 at the time of this answer) for support on the latest Internet Explorer releases. *RichFaces 3 is old!*

Answer (score 0):

Brian Leathem is right. But if for some other reasons you are forced not to change the compatibility mode, you can try this:

Richfaces3.x fails with IE11 because of missing functions like LOG.debug(""), LOG.warn("") and LOG.error("");

Include a javascript file like this to "override" this functions:

```
LOG = new Object();
LOG.debug = function(msg)
{
   console.log("debug: " + msg);
};
LOG.warn = function(msg)
{
   console.log("warn: " + msg);
};
LOG.error = function(msg)
{
   console.log("error: " + msg);
};
```

I tried this in an application that used only the ajax components of richfaces3.x. Maybe using all richfaces taglibs this may not work.